# Combine TCP Sockets and Restful endpoints

Tags: java, rest, sockets, spring-integration

I would like to point out to me where to look about(Java), how to combine Restful Api and TCP Sockets. Request are coming from the Restful api and will be propagate to the Socket! It is possible to do that with Spring Integration? Or another framework?
EDIT:
I already have the program which is communicating with the Socket Server.
The communication must be synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom servlet to process my data.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you mean by `propagate to the Socket`. 
So I will assume that you wish to make a connection to a remote *TCP* server from your java application, on receiving a REST connection on an endpoint.
How you make the connection will depend on your specific use case,

- synchronous vs asynchronous
- volume of information to be transmitted between TCP server and client
- any specific protocol for message communication
- Do you get to design your own protocol, say using `protobuf` for example.

A few options you may consider,

- Plain native java `SocketChannel`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html
- Asynchronous: AsynchronousSocketChannel https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html
- kryonet library: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet
- Apache MINA: https://mina.apache.org/mina-project sample TCP Client code: https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch2-basics/ch2.3-sample-tcp-client.html
- `gRPC` if you are going to design your own client-server communication  - https://grpc.io/

Comment: By the word "propagate" I mean one system using the Restful API and the other is using only socket to communicate!

Comment: yes, that's what I thought; my comments apply then.

Comment: I have found a solution with custom servlets.